# Can't run unit tests in Xcode 8 with earlier unit test configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode8

I ran into this issue after upgrading to Xcode 8. When running the tests I get this error at run time:

`/Users/<me>/work/<appname>/Build/Intermediates/<appname>.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/<appname>UnitTests.build/Script-231C35D610AC1F5000D830C2.sh: line 3: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunUnitTests: No such file or directory`

The sh script in the error message is trying to access the RunUnitTests tool and  fails. I assume this tool has been removed in Xcode 8. It seems that for my project Xcode tries to run tests in a way that is no longer supported. If I create a brand new project no such script is created and I can run tests.

Any idea what settings I need to update in my project to get the tests running again? I tried the 'Update to recommended settings' checklist but it doesn't solve this issue.

Answer (score 22):

It seems I only needed to remove the Run Script phase that invoked that script.

Comment: I also had to do a clean build folder before it would work.

Comment: Clear `Framework Search Paths` to remove an `ld` warning.

Comment: This is done by selecting your project in Navigator, then select the Test Target from left column, select `Build Phases` and remove the `Run Script` section.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Run Script from the Build Phases didn't help me.

I simply copied /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools/RunUnitTests from my older Xcode into my XCode 8 package content. Give it right permissions:
RWXR-XR-X

And it worked for me.